# InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace

Tags: mysql, innodb

i have this problem opening mysql server on Xaamp

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    If you need more help, copy and post this
    entire log window on the forums
and error logs

```
enter code here

2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-04-06 19:28:56 2334 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Binlog end
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: 2015-04-06 19:28:56 3576 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1: Does the file still exist? If not: Do you have a virus scanner active on the system? This might have quarantined the file....

Comment: where is your Ibdata1 file? did you try changing the path of the datadir?  Did you delete data in the datadir??

Comment: first of all thank you for responding.i did accidentally delete Ibdata1!what i should do BK435?and norbert van Nobelen

Answer (score 8):

This solution worked for me.

1. Navigate to C:\Xampp\mysql\data
2. Delete all ib_logfile's
3. Delete the ibdata1 file
4. Restart Xampp server

Comment: Dont ever delete ibdata1 & ib_logfile's before backup it first!

Comment: Can someone just answer it in Ubuntu point of view. I mean what would be the path in Ubuntu?

Comment: Path in Ubuntu is `/var/lib/mysql`